# configure Squid3 proxy server on Ubuntu with caching and logging

Tags: ubuntu-11.10, squid

I have a ubuntu 11.10 machine. 
Installed Squid3.
When i configure the squid as http_access allow all, everything works fine.
my current configuration mostly default is as follows:

```
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing Configuration File: /etc/squid3/squid.conf (depth 0)
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: acl manager proto cache_object
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: acl SSL_ports port 443
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 80     # http
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 21     # ftp
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 443        # https
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 70     # gopher
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 210        # wais
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 # unregistered ports
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 280        # http-mgmt
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 488        # gss-http
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 591        # filemaker
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: acl Safe_ports port 777        # multiling http
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: acl CONNECT method CONNECT
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: http_access allow manager localhost
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: http_access deny manager
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: http_access deny !Safe_ports
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: http_access allow localhost
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: http_access deny all
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: http_port 3128
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: refresh_pattern ^ftp:      1440    20% 10080
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: refresh_pattern ^gopher:   1440    0%  1440
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0    0%  0
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: refresh_pattern .      0   20% 4320
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: http_access allow all
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: cache_mem 512 MB
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: logformat squid3 %ts.%03tu %6tr %>a %Ss/%03>Hs %<st %rm %ru
2012/09/10 13:19:57| Processing: access_log /home/panshul/squidCache/log/access.log squid3
```

The problem starts when I enable the following line:

```
access_log /home/panshul/squidCache/log/access.log
```

I start to get `proxy server is refusing connections error` in the browser. 
on commenting out the above line in my config, things go back to normal.

The second problem starts when i add the following line to my config:

```
cache_dir ufs /home/panshul/squidCache/cache 100 16 256
```

The squid server fails to start.

Any suggestions what am I missing in the config. Please help.!!

Comment: I have been starting the squid server with root privileges to avoid any permission issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding "squid" to the end of your access_log directive.

```
access_log /home/panshul/squidCache/log/access.log squid
```

Solution here possibly... [Ubuntu Forum - Squid config solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1419364)